# After buying Expo application services, will expo team create build and publish it to app store for us?

Tags: react-native, build, expo, eas

Since I am facing a lot of issues with expo eas build, I am planning to buy the production expo application services plan. But just before that I am unable to understand how will it help. Will the expo team take my project and create build for it?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for this forum. You will need to contact Expo directly.

Comment: I did contact them and it's been 2 weeks. I needed to know if someone else has bought their plan, would be a great help.

Comment: I get it. When I need answers, I often try any forum that seems at all relevant. SO is not the place in this situation. Not that there's any harm in asking. Just don't get your hopes up for a speedy response. You may also want to try Reactiflux on Discord. Good luck.